# Titanium iOS app to Android

Tags: android, ios, titanium

I built an iOS app for a company i know, now I'm trying to make that same app for android. Just clicking the "Android" button in the xml file doesn't work. Do I have to rewrite the whole app again or is there some other way I can easily make that same app for android?

Comment: Probably your Titanium code for iOS works for android too. You will need to change the code little wherever needed. Did you try running the code in android emulator? What have you got?

Comment: Yeah I tried it, I'm currently fixing all code, thx for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You don't need to rewrite the whole code again. But you should have to make some platform specific codes. Also some controls like `Toolbar` will not be available for Android. You can check the platform using `Ti.Platform.osname` or `getOsname()` method, which will return the osname(android/ios). In short, all other code will be work in android platform also.